# Linear layout cutting material cards shadow

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, layout, material-design

I'm making a weather app with material cards and its shadows.
I've found a way to center them using a Linear Layout, but it cuts off the shadows.
How can I prevent this? Is there a way to align them without using a linear layout or a frame layout?

Here's my layout code:
I used a FrameLayout as root, there's my LinearLayout containing both material cards, I just wanted them to be centred as a group, if you know another way to do this please tell me!

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/background"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:fontFamily="cursive"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textColor="#FFF"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Your location's weather in a touch!"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    android:textSize="17.3sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_temperature"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="30°C"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
            android:textSize="50sp" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/cv_data"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_conditions"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="Scatted Clouds"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pb_loading"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:elevation="20dp"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_city_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>
```

[image: screenshoot of my problem]

Comment: What is your `<LinearLayout>` inside of? It will be easier to answer if we can see the entire layout.

Comment: Updated with the entire layout file.

Comment: It is obvious by the image you posted that the blue color background hides the shadow

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like your layout would be better as a `ConstraintLayout` instead of a `FrameLayout`, but we can still make what you have work.

The problem is that (on newer Android versions), the shadows for a `CardView` are actually drawn *outside* the view's bounds. Normally this is fine, but if the `CardView` is inside a parent, that parent can clip the shadows if the parent doesn't have enough room to show the shadows.

In your case, the "easy fix" is actually extremely easy. Change your `LinearLayout`'s width to `match_parent`; this will give the cards room to draw their shadows.

## Edit

What I said above will solve the shadows on the sides of each card, but won't solve the shadows above the top card or below the bottom card. Again, in the spirit of a quick fix, I'd suggest adding these attributes to your LinearLayout:

```
android:paddingTop="8dp"
android:paddingBottom="8dp"
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

Comment: Thank you! It's my first app, and I'm making it just to learn some android studio, so easy fixes are allowed! :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `height` and add change `layout_gravity` to `gravity`, like the code bellow:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:gravity="center_vertical"
  android:orientation="vertical">
```

It probably will solve your problems =]

If you want to improve your code, I suggest you not to set fixed width and height, it cand bring you problems in some devices. You can also load `xmlns:card_view` only once, at your `LinearLayout`, that it's your very first tag

Comment: Thank you, they're already aligned, but the main problem was the shadows. 
If I erase xmlns:card_view from the second card_view, its attributes turn red  ¯\_(•_• )_/¯

Comment: Android creates this shadows out of the CardView. Using his parent ViewGroup as `wrap_content` it may not show the entire shadow. In this case, you can use `match_parent` into parent ViewGroup. And sorry, I forgot to say to add `xmlns:card_view` to the LinearLayout that is your very first tag from its layout. By doing this, you can use `card_view:..` in any of his children =]